# Getting error 500.30 when I try to run my asp.net core 3.1 app on azure

Tags: asp.net-core, azure-web-app-service

I have an app that is asp.net core 3.1 connected to a sql server database and a secrets file.  I can run this all locally, and it works.

I published my app to Azure, migrated my db there, and created a Key Vault.  All of those say they were successful.

When I try to publish my app, it says "Configured" for the db and the Key vault, and the app deploys successfully.  However, when it redirects me to the website where my app should be running, I get a 500.30 error.

These are the errors I was getting yesterday: (I'm not sure what I'm getting now, because I cannot seem to find the page on Azure where I found these, and I've spent about 20 minutes looking for it)

Error #1

```
Application: w3wp.exe
CoreCLR Version: 4.700.20.26901
.NET Core Version: 3.1.6
Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
Exception Info: System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'implementationInstance')
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceCollectionServiceExtensions.AddSingleton[TService](IServiceCollection services, TService implementationInstance)
   at RecipeCompendiumTool.Startup.ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services) in C:\Users\julie\source\repos\RecipeCompendiumTool\Startup.cs:line 44
   at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor, Boolean wrapExceptions)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.ConfigureServicesBuilder.InvokeCore(Object instance, IServiceCollection services)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.ConfigureServicesBuilder.<>c__DisplayClass9_0.<Invoke>g__Startup|0(IServiceCollection serviceCollection)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.ConfigureServicesBuilder.Invoke(Object instance, IServiceCollection services)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.ConfigureServicesBuilder.<>c__DisplayClass8_0.<Build>b__0(IServiceCollection services)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.GenericWebHostBuilder.UseStartup(Type startupType, HostBuilderContext context, IServiceCollection services)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.GenericWebHostBuilder.<>c__DisplayClass12_0.<UseStartup>b__0(HostBuilderContext context, IServiceCollection services)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostBuilder.CreateServiceProvider()
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostBuilder.Build()
   at RecipeCompendiumTool.Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\Users\julie\source\repos\RecipeCompendiumTool\Program.cs:line 16
```

Error #2

```
Application '/LM/W3SVC/312799001/ROOT' with physical root 'D:\home\site\wwwroot\' hit unexpected managed exception, exception code = '0xe0434352'. First 30KB characters of captured stdout and stderr logs:
Unhandled exception. System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'implementationInstance')
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceCollectionServiceExtensions.AddSingleton[TService](IServiceCollection services, TService implementationInstance)
   at RecipeCompendiumTool.Startup.ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services) in C:\Users\julie\source\repos\RecipeCompendiumTool\Startup.cs:line 44
   at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor, Boolean wrapExceptions)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.ConfigureServicesBuilder.InvokeCore(Object instance, IServiceCollection services)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.ConfigureServicesBuilder.<>c__DisplayClass9_0.<Invoke>g__Startup|0(IServiceCollection serviceCollection)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.ConfigureServicesBuilder.Invoke(Object instance, IServiceCollection services)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.ConfigureServicesBuilder.<>c__DisplayClass8_0.<Build>b__0(IServiceCollection services)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.GenericWebHostBuilder.UseStartup(Type startupType, HostBuilderContext context, IServiceCollection services)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.GenericWebHostBuilder.<>c__DisplayClass12_0.<UseStartup>b__0(HostBuilderContext context, IServiceCollection services)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostBuilder.CreateServiceProvider()
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostBuilder.Build()
   at RecipeCompendiumTool.Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\Users\julie\source\repos\RecipeCompendiumTool\Program.cs:line 16

Process Id: 6904.
File Version: 13.1.20169.6. Description: IIS ASP.NET Core Module V2 Request Handler. Commit: 62c098bc170f50feca15916e81cb7f321ffc52ff
```

Error #3

```
Application '/LM/W3SVC/312799001/ROOT' with physical root 'D:\home\site\wwwroot\' failed to load coreclr. Exception message:
CLR worker thread exited prematurely
Process Id: 6904.
File Version: 13.1.20169.6. Description: IIS ASP.NET Core Module V2 Request Handler. Commit: 62c098bc170f50feca15916e81cb7f321ffc52ff
```

My Startup.cs file

```
        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }
        public IWebHostEnvironment Environment { get; }

        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration, IWebHostEnvironment environment)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
            Environment = environment;
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddAuthentication(IISServerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);

            services.AddControllersWithViews();
            services.AddRazorPages();

            services.Configure<FormOptions>(x => x.ValueCountLimit = 1000000000);

            services.AddSingleton<IEmailConfiguration>(Configuration.GetSection("EmailConfiguration").Get<EmailConfiguration>());
            services.AddTransient<IEmailService, EmailService>();
            services.AddSingleton<IEmailSender, EmailSender>();

            services.AddControllers().AddNewtonsoftJson(options =>
                options.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore);

            services.AddIdentity<RecipeCompendiumToolUser, IdentityRole>()
                .AddEntityFrameworkStores<RecipeCompendiumToolContext>()
                .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

            services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.CompatibilityVersion.Version_3_0)
                .AddRazorPagesOptions(options =>
                {
                    options.Conventions.AuthorizeAreaFolder("Identity", "/Account/Manage");
                    options.Conventions.AuthorizeAreaPage("Identity", "/Account/Logout");
                });


            if (Environment.IsDevelopment())
            {
                services.AddRazorPages().AddRazorRuntimeCompilation();

                services.AddDbContext<RecipeCompendiumToolContext>(options =>
                        options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
            }
            else if (Environment.IsStaging())
            {
                services.AddRazorPages().AddRazorRuntimeCompilation();

                services.AddDbContext<RecipeCompendiumToolContext>(options =>
                        options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("TestConnection")));
            }
            else if (Environment.IsProduction())
            {
                services.AddDbContext<RecipeCompendiumToolContext>(options =>
                        options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("ProdConnection")));
            }
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)//, RecipeCompendiumToolSeedData seeder)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
                // TODO: The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
                app.UseHsts();
            }
            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseStaticFiles();

            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseAuthentication();
            app.UseAuthorization();

            //seeder.InitializeSeedData();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
                endpoints.MapRazorPages();
                endpoints.MapControllers();
            });
        }
    }
```

Comment: As it appears from the stacktrace, can you check for a parameter named 'implementationInstance' in EmailConfiguration or EmailSender ? Apparently, this parameter is not added in your App settings/Key Vault settings.
And most probably that's why, you are getting Error#3 until and unless there are few more errors which are hidden behind the Error#1 and 2.

Comment: I went back one commit at a time, and there were about 5 different issues - some on Startup.cs (a duplicate line and my model/call to initialize seed data), the various .json files (it errors when I remove the EmailConfiguration section), and for some reason, in the auto-generated _LoginPartial.cshtml file created when I installed Microsoft's Identity software.  I'm still working through the first & last one, but I've fixed the others.

Comment: Out of the errors which you have mentioned, which one is remaining? And which ones you removed? Also, did u check the parameter 'implementationInstance'?

Comment: I don't know which errors remain - I've searched all over Azure's website and I can't find where I saw those in the first place.  If you know how I can find them, I'll update with what remains.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed - there may have been other issues, but if you're deploying to Azure with a db, make sure your db's firewall settings have "Allow Azure services and resources to access this server" set to YES.